# Trying to open a home window after completing the login page

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, designer

```
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.verticalWidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.login)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        
        self.pushButton2 = QPushButton(self.verticalWidget)
        self.pushButton2.setObjectName(u"pushButton2")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton2)
        self.pushButton2.setDisabled(True)
```

```
    def login(self):
        email = self.emailLineEdit.text()
        password = self.passwordLineEdit.text()
        if email and password is not None:
            mydb = mc.connect(
                host="localhost",
                user="root",
                password=os.getenv('mysqlpass'),
                database="cinedeck")

            mycursor = mydb.cursor()
            query = f"SELECT email, password FROM user_info WHERE email = '{email}'"
            mycursor.execute(query)
            result = mycursor.fetchone()
            mydb.close()
            if result:
                if result[1] == password:
                    QMessageBox.about(self, "Success ✅", "Successfully logged into Cinedeck! Click again to continue.")
                    self.pushButton2.setDisabled(False)
                    self.pushButton2.clicked.connect(self.openhomescreen)
                else:
                    QMessageBox.about(self, "Error ⚠️", "Incorrect Password!")
                
            else:
                QMessageBox.about(self, "Error ⚠️", "Account does not exist!")
        else:
            QMessageBox.about(self, "Error ", "Please Enter Email or Password.")
            
    def openhomescreen(self):
        self.selfhomewindow.setupUi(self)
```

Could you suggest an easier method to open another window after the login. I tried doing a QMessageBox message that would open the new window when the button on it is clicked but I'm not able to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "an easier method"? Easier than what?

Comment: i meant that this method isnt working. i wanted to know where ive made a mistake

Comment: We cannot know, as your code is insufficient to understand *what* doesn't work. Please [edit] your question and provide [mre].

Comment: shud i link the repo to this project?

Comment: https://github.com/koshyj8/cine-deck/tree/master/CineDeck

Comment: No. I said to **edit** the question and provide a MRE, not add a link to your full code. Please read the above link and follow its instructions.

Comment: when i try to run your code i get an error: import mysql.connector as mc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'

Comment: a working example would be good